# c# WCF catch Fault Exceptions of Base type

Tags: c#, wcf

I have been looking everywhere to find out how to catch a base fault contract type in c#.  I would like to have all my fault contracts inherit from one class and have one catch(FaultException fex) in the MVC controller.

**DataContracts**

```
[DataContract]
public class BaseClass1 
{ }

[DataContract]
public class Class2 : BaseClass1 
{ }
```

**Service**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(BaseClass1))]
    [FaultContract(typeof(Class2))]  //Do I need this one?
    void ThrowClass2();
}

public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public void ThrowClass2()
    {
        throw new FaultException<Class2>(new Class2(), "Class2 Reason");
    }
}
```

**Service Consumer**

```
FaultTestService.Service1Client client = null;
try
{
    client = new FaultTestService.Service1Client();
    client.ThrowAmpFaults("InvalidParameter", 0);
}
catch (FaultException<Namespace.BaseClass1> fex)
{
    //DOES NOT GO IN HERE AS I WOULD EXPECT   
}
catch (FaultException fex)
{
    //Other Possible Option
    MessageFault fault = fex.CreateMessageFault();  
    var fe1 = fault.GetDetail<BaseClass1>();
    //This throws a serialization exception it needs <Class2>
}
```

Please let me know if either of these catch statements can be fixed to do what I am looking for.

Answer (score 5):

That syntax will not work in C#. Consider the folowing "workaround" instead.

```
try
{
    throw new FaultException<DerivedClass2>(new DerivedClass2());
}
catch (FaultException fex)
{
    bool handled = false;
    Type fexType = fex.GetType();
    if (fexType.IsGenericType && fexType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(FaultException<>))
    {
        if (typeof(BaseClass1).IsAssignableFrom(fexType.GetGenericArguments()[0]))
        {
            object detail = fexType.GetProperty("Detail").GetValue(fex, null);

            // Use detail here.

            handled = true;
        }
    }

    if (!handled)
        throw; // Don't know how to handle. Re-throw.
}
```

This can be simplified if we disregard the unusual case where `Detail == null` but the constructed generic type matches. I'll also use the C# dynamic keyword to simplify it a little further.

```
try
{
    throw new FaultException<DerivedClass2>(new DerivedClass2());
}
catch (FaultException fex)
{
    bool handled = false;
    Type fexType = fex.GetType();
    if (fexType.IsGenericType && fexType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(FaultException<>))
    {
        object detail = ((dynamic)fex).Detail;
        if (detail is BaseClass1) // true for subclasses too!
        {
            // Use detail here.
        }

    }

    if (!handled)
        throw; // Don't know how to handle. Re-throw. 
}
```

The other thing to consider is whether you should just use `throw new FaultException<BaseClass1>(new DerivedClass2())`. This way of throwing will let you catch using the code you originally provided.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, there is no way to do this. There is no relationship between `FaultException<T1>` and `FaultException<T2>` simply because `T1` may be a subclass of `T2`.

Comment: But what's the reason of this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Your client needs a [message inspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047.aspx). We had a similar [situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441647/multiple-name-spaces-in-a-soap-fault-message-causing-faultexception-deserializati) where the server was throwing various exceptions and they all ended up as a FaultException.