# WCF custom fault exception not caught correctly in client

Tags: wcf, faultexception

I'm trying to create some custom `FaultException`. I've made a `DataContract` class called `CreateFault`.

```
[DataContract]
public class CreateFault
{
    private string report;

    public CreateFault(string message)
    {
        this.report = message;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Message
    {
        get { return this.report; }
        set { this.report = value; }
    }
}
```

I'm then throwing the fault in a service method.

In `IService1.cs`

```
[OperationContract]
[FaultContract(typeof(CreateFault))]
void TestFaultException();
```

and in `Service1.cs`

```
public void TestFaultException()
{
    throw new FaultException<CreateFault>(new CreateFault("CreateFault message"), "Message abt exception");
}
```

I catch the `FaultException` in my client.

```
private void btnTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        ServiceReference1.Service1Client client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
        client.TestFaultException();
    }
    catch (FaultException<CreateFault> ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Detail.Message, "Success", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }
    catch (FaultException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Failure", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Now here comes the problem. When I create a WCF Service Application project in Visual Studio 2010 it works like expected. The error is caught in:

```
catch (FaultException<CreateFault> ex)
```

But when I create a WCF Service Library project with my custom `FaultExceptions` the client does not recognize my custom exception. It instead catches the error in:

```
catch (FaultException ex)
```

Why does it not work with WCF Service Application Project?

Edit:
This is what i get during debugging when it catches the exception in

```
catch (FaultException ex)
```

(typed ?ex in Immediate window)

{"Message abt exception"}

```
[System.ServiceModel.FaultException<WpfApplication1.ServiceReference2.CreateFault>]: {"Message abt exception"}
base {System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException}: {"Message abt exception"}
Action: "http://tempuri.org/IService1/TestFaultExceptionCreateFaultFault"
Code: {System.ServiceModel.FaultCode}
Message: "Message abt exception"
Reason: {Message abt exception}
```

Edit2:

Found the problem. I had two Service references who both had the CreateFault DataContract. And it was using the wrong one when i ran the program.

When i changed to

```
catch (FaultException<ServiceReference2.CreateFault> ex)
```

it worked

Comment: By all accounts it should catch the exception. Could you check if the catch exception is a generic "FaultException<Type>" or just "FaultException".

Comment: this is what i get when i type ?ex in Immediate Window ?ex
{"Message abt exception"}
    [System.ServiceModel.FaultException<WpfApplication1.ServiceReference2.CreateFault>]: {"Message abt exception"}
    base {System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException}: {"Message abt exception"}
    Action: "http://tempuri.org/IService1/TestFaultExceptionCreateFaultFault"
    Code: {System.ServiceModel.FaultCode}
    Message: "Message abt exception"
    Reason: {Message abt exception}

Comment: Found the problem. I had two Service references who both had the CreateFault DataContract. And it was using the wrong one when i ran the program.

When i changed to

    catch (FaultException<ServiceReference2.CreateFault> ex) 

it worked

Comment: Could you add your solution as an answer and mark it as the accepted answer please? That way, we can all see that the question has been answered (and you might get votes for it :-))

Comment: ok, will do. Just have to wait until tomorrow until i am allowed to press accept as answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the problem. I had two Service references who both had the CreateFault DataContract. And it was using the wrong one when i ran the program.

When i changed to

```
catch (FaultException<ServiceReference2.CreateFault> ex)
```

it worked